# event/callback on block update?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I am attempting to put together a custom block that produces an embed from a third party. The embed is generated by an external script scanning for an element with a data attribute holding a unique identifier. I have the basic version of this block working just fine. However, I am now trying to have this embed display dynamically in the edit screen when you enter the identifier.

My edit function looks like this:

```
function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes } ) {

    const onChangeIdentifier = (value) => {
        setAttributes({ identifier: value });
    };

    return (
        <div id = {`embed-${ instanceId }`}>
    {attributes.identifier
    ? 
        <div  
            data-identifier= { attributes.identifier }
        >

        </div>

     : 

        <Placeholder
            instructions={ __( 'Enter identifier.' ) }
        >
            <PlainText
                placeholder={ __(
                        'Enter identifier here…'
                    ) }
                value={ attributes.identifier || '' }
                onChange={ onChangeIdentifier }
            />
    </Placeholder>

    }
    </div>);
}

export default withInstanceId( Edit );
```

Almost everything happens correctly. When the identifier is entered it swaps out the placeholder for the data-identifier element, but the embed can't be generated because the third party script only automatically triggers a scan when the DOM loads. They do provide a function to manually call a scan in the event you create an embed via ajax. **Here is the issue:** I do not know where to call this function to have it correctly render the embed. (I can verify it works properly, as I can edit the block and call the function in console and have it update correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a `useEffect` hook subscribed to the `attributes.identifier` to call the script.

something like:

```
function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes } ) {

    useEffect( () => {

      // this will fire whenever the attribute changes.
      thirdPartyScriptFunctionName();

    },[attributes.identifier])

     const onChangeIdentifier = (value) => {
        setAttributes({ identifier: value });
     };

    return (
         <div id = {`embed-${ instanceId }`}>
             {attributes.identifier
         ? 
       <div  
           data-identifier= { attributes.identifier }
        >

        </div>

     : 

        <Placeholder
            instructions={ __( 'Enter identifier.' ) }
        >
            <PlainText
                placeholder={ __(
                        'Enter identifier here…'
                    ) }
                value={ attributes.identifier || '' }
                onChange={ onChangeIdentifier }
            />
       </Placeholder>

    }
     </div>);
}

 export default withInstanceId( Edit );
```

You'll need to get the `useEffect` hook from the wp.element global.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed it to, thanks!